# Get plugin info from Wordpress.org repository API with plain PHP code

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org, api

[The documentation of the Wordpress.org API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API) is quite terrible. It links to a website that gives a 502 Bad Gateway error.

To be precise, how should my POST request look to the http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/ URL, to get, say, plugin information for the plugin `advanced-custom-fields`? I tried this:

```
$array(
  'action' => 'plugin_information',
  'body'   => 'O:8:"stdClass";s:22:"advanced-custom-fields";'
);
```

but it returns `Action not implemented` error, and I can't quite figure out where to find a correct example.

I really want to do this without the Wordpress function `wp_remote_post`, because I'm trying to implement this outside of a WP install, and to be fully honest, I'm trying to do it in a Ruby app, using [php-serialize gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/php-serialize).

I only need the PHP array structure, so I could request it with a Ruby `net/http` request.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to the question I marked as duplicate. If you're trying it outside the WP context, them I'm sorry to tell you that it's off topic for this site.

Comment: Oh wow, that was basically all I needed. It seems you can send the plugin slug behind the URI, and you get a serialized stdClass. Thanks mate